# Why hyperlink not open in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have 3 file html:
**force_hyperlink_open_in_new_window.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Force hyperlink open in new window</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="force_hyperlink_open_in_new_window_01.html">Foo</a>
<a href="force_hyperlink_open_in_new_window_02.html">Bar</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[href^="http://"]')
            .not('[target="_blank"]')
            .attr('target', '_blank');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**force_hyperlink_open_in_new_window_01.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>01</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: tomato;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**force_hyperlink_open_in_new_window_02.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>02</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: limegreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Why 2 hyperlinks don't open in new tab (I use Google Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit))?

Comment: Your "href" attribute values do not start with "http://".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select anchors starting with `http://` while your links are relative and don't start with `http://`.

Change the JQuery selector to general anchors: `$('a')` and it will add your target, if they don't already have it. See https://jsfiddle.net/k7ww81ee/

```
$('a')
        .not('[target="_blank"]')
        .attr('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be because the hrefs don't start with http://. Also, you can force opening links in new tabs by putting this line in head:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your href does not match they not have http.

Change:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]')
```

to

```
$('a')
```

to grep all links.